# Randomizing Texture coordinates through nodes, but not enough variety

Tags: texturing, node-editor, shader-nodes, texture-coordinates, bump

I'm working on a piece where theres a brick wall.

I'm using a noise texture to bump map to create a certain look, and I Alt+D'd the bricks so I'd be able to edit the material in one go.

The problem I'm having is that they are noticeable the same texture repeated.

[image: the grey bricks have the same front]

I followed two separate guides on how to randomize texture map, but it seems to not be working. This is my node set up

[image: Nodes]

The Object info random node is hooked up, but having duplicated an object twice, there is no noticeable changes in the texture format.

[image]

The more I duplicate SOME will be slightly different, but here's what's weird. I also have a color ramp node set up to change the color of the brick slightly with each iteration. I favored one color more than the other in the gradient so most will be a dark grey, and the other will be a dirty yellow.

I noticed that if I duplicate the original brick, every time it's grey, the texture is the same, but when it's yellow the texture is different... BUT the same as every YELLOW texture. This, despite both being assigned random.

[image]

is there something I'm obviously missing?

Comment: Any one have any advice? Should I clarify anything?

Answer (score 1):

Object info node random value outputs float value from 0 to 1 (0 0.1 0.01 0.5 0.9 1 etc) your setup essentially offsets the coordinates by that number, it is random per object, but offset is to small so result you see seams repeating.

Solution to that is you have to add math multiply node for example 100 times so your random value will be from 0 to 100 and that will move your coordinates much more from brick to brick, then every brick should have visibly different normal.

And your colours are mostly grey because grey colour takes more percentage of the ramp so in effect you have that percentage/chance of grey bricks then the warm ones.
You can change the positions of those colours on ramp, you can also alt copy your brick until you get your preferred colour.

Extra tip, if you just alt copied your brick with move you can repeat that action with Shift+R its shortcut for repeat last step.

Try this node setup:
[image: random texture coordinate per brick object1]

(I probably had different size of brick then yours so had to adjust the noise scale but hopefully it solves what you asked for)

Here you have also video showing all of above (sorry its not edited and have no audio):
https://youtu.be/cdRkEE-xb64